# Find strings between quotes, but before colon?

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

I've tested at all sorts of examples and non of them seem to work for me.

Given a string like this:

```
"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}
```

Is there a RegEx I can use to get just the strings within the double quotes that precede a colon?  In this case I just want FOO,BAR,FIND,ME.  No other values.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `[A-Z0-9]+(?=\"(?=:))` will work for the sample string provided.

```
$string = '"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}'
$matches = ([regex]'[A-Z0-9]+(?=\"(?=:))').Matches($string)
$matches.value
```

`$matches.value` returns (as an array):

```
FOO
BAR
FIND
ME
```

**Regex explanation**

`[A-Z0-9]` - Match any of the characters between `A-Z` and `0-9`

`+` - Match as many times as possible

`(?=...)` - Positive lookahead, only matches if the specific character in the lookahead follows.

`\"` - match the character `"` literally

`:` - Match the character `:` literally.

Put it together, `[A-Z0-9]+` matches `A-Z0-9` as many times as possible and `(?=\"(?=:))` matches only when it is followed by `"` and then `:`.

More info on the regex: https://regex101.com/r/PsKS6N/1/

Comment: why not `(?=\"(?=:))` → `(?=\":)`? And why not a lookbehind in front?

Comment: An oversight, admittedly, `(?=\":)` is more concise. Originally I used a lookbehind in front, but based on the given string it's not needed to return the desired result.

Comment: Since I was really looking for a RegEx I choose this answer.  I edited the answer to  `[^"]+(?=\":)` to fit the extra data no present in the example.  It works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your input object is just one missing `{` from being valid JSON, so if we convert it like so...

```
$json = '{"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}}'
```

We can then retrieve the name of the parent node (`FOO`), and the name's of each of the properties as well.

```
$json = '{"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}}'
$objects = ConvertFrom-Json $json

($objects.PSobject.Properties) | % {
    $parent = $_.Name
    $childrenNames = $_.Value.PSObject.Properties | % {$_.Name}
    }
[pscustomobject]@{ParentColumn=$parent;ChildrensNames=$childrenNames}


ParentColumn ChildrensNames 
------------ -------------- 
FOO          {BAR, FIND, ME}
```

Let me know if this gets you moving in the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at some examples tells me that in PowerShell you can do something like this:

```
$results = $data | Select-String '"([^"]+)":' -AllMatches
```

which should store the group number 1 (the first and only parentheses) in

```
$results[0].Groups[1].Value
$results[1].Groups[1].Value
...
```

`[^"]` matches any non-double-quote character

Comment: Thanks for updating; while this is a working solution, using a _cmdlet_ for in-memory operations is heavy-handed and inefficient, unfortunately. The related expression-mode operator, `-match`, currently only supports a _single_ match (reflected in the automatic `$Matches` variable), but [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes bringing the equivalent of `Select-String -AllMatches` (`[regex]::Matches()`) to expressions via a _new operator_, tentatively named `-matchall`.

Comment: @mklement0 I don't even know what a cmdlet is :-D. My attempt was a blind one, I barely know what _PowerShell_ is!

Comment: :) I had a hunch, and it's why I offered some context; if you do want to learn about cmdlets and pipelines, [`about_Pipelines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) is a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

**If you must use a *regex*** to solve this problem, here's a concise solution (PSv3+):

```
[regex]::Matches(
  '"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}',
  '(?<=")[^"]+(?=":)'
).Value   # -> 'FOO', 'BAR', 'FIND', 'ME'
```

- Regex `(?<=")[^"]+(?=":)` matches the *content* of all `"..."`-enclosed tokens that are immediately followed by a `:`; the initial `"` and the following `":`are not included in the match due to use of look-behind - `(?<=...)` - and look-ahead - `(?=...)` - assertions, and the content is matched by `[^"]+`, a nonempty run (`+`) of characters other than `"` (`[^"]`).
- `.Value` extracts the matched string from each [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance returned by the (implicit) enumeration of the [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection) collection returned by the  [`[regex]::Matches()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_).

---

**If the input is (effectively) *JSON***, consider a `ConvertFrom-Json`-based approach, as in [FoxDeploy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937640/45375).

Here's a *generalization* of that approach, via **a function that walks an arbitrary object graph to report a flat list of its property names** with **input from a (nested) custom object that `ConvertFrom-Json` created from JSON**:

```
# Define the walker function:
# Get all property names in a given object's hierarchy.
function get-PropertyName {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $InputObject)
  process {   
    if ($null -eq $InputObject -or $InputObject -is [DbNull] -or $InputObject.GetType().IsPrimitive -or $InputObject.GetType() -in [string], [datetime], [datetimeoffset], [decimal], [bigint]) {
      # A null-like value or a primitive or quasi-primitive type:
      # No constituent properties to report.
    }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
      # A collection of sorts (other than a string or dictionary (hash table)), 
      # recurse on its elements.
      foreach ($o in $InputObject) { get-PropertyName $o }
    }
    else { 
      # A non-quasi-primitive scalar object or a dictionary:
      # enumerate its properties / entries.
      $props = if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) { $InputObject.GetEnumerator() } else { $InputObject.psobject.properties }
      foreach ($p in $props) {
        $p.Name
        # Recurse
        get-PropertyName $p.Value
      }
    }
  }
}

# Make the input string a JSON string.
$str = '"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}'
$json = '{' + $str + '}'

# Convert the JSON string to a custom-object hierarchy and let the walker
# function enumerate all of its properties as a flat list.
$json | ConvertFrom-Json | get-PropertyName # -> 'FOO', 'BAR', 'FIND', 'ME'
```

*Caveat*: The `get-PropertyName` function doesn't check for circular references between properties, which could result in an infinite recursion; with JSON as the input, that isn't a concern, however.

Answer (score 0):

this is likely too fragile, but it does work with the limited sample you provided ... [*grin*]

```
$InStuff = '"FOO":{"BAR":"0x507A","FIND":"DONTFINDME","ME":["0x3214"]}'

$InStuff -split ':' |
    Where-Object {$_ -match '"$'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match ',')
            {
            $_.Split(',')[1]
            }
            else
            {
            $_
            }} |
    ForEach-Object {$_.Trim('{"')}
```

output ...

```
FOO
BAR
FIND
ME
```